# Java program tips

Tags: java, exception, methods

I am trying to make a quiz game. I was wondering when I run the program, I get an infinite loop on my `while` statements. When I run my code after I entered the game it prints the question, but before I input my answer it gives me an `Exception` error. I am not quite sure on how to fix it.

```
/**
     * @(#)QuizGameFinal2.java
     *
     *
     * @author
     * @version 1.00 2013/4/30
     */

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.lang.Math;
    import java.lang.String;
    public class QuizGameFinal2
    {

        public static void main(String[]args)
        {

    int option_Selected = 0;
        int option_Single_Player = 1;
        int option_Multiplayer = 2;
        int answer = 0;
        int player_One_Answer = 0;
        int player_Two_Answer = 0;
        String response;
        int player_One_Winnings = 0;
        int player_Two_Winnings = 0;
        int winnings = 0;
        int computer_Winnings = 0;
        double computer_Answer = 0;

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);



        say_Intro();







        say_Before_First_Question();
        question_One();
        human_Answer();
        while (answer < 1 && answer >= 4);
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 3");
        }

        if (answer == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Correct Next Question");
            question_Two();
            human_Answer();
                while (answer < 1 && answer >= 4);
                {
                System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 3");
                }
            if (answer == 1 )
            {
                System.out.println("Correct Next Question");
                question_Three();
                human_Answer();

                 while (answer < 1 && answer > 4);
                 {
                    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 3");
                 }

                if (answer == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Correct Next Question");

                }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect you win 1000 dollers");
                        winnings = 1000;
                    }

            }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect you win 500 dollers");
                        winnings = 500;
                    }


        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect you win 0 dollers");
            winnings = 0;
        }





        } // End of main method




        public static void say_Intro()      // Intro Method
        {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the QuizGame");          // Player selects which mode
        }


        public static void say_Before_First_Question()      // Before game method
        {


                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(" If you get a question wrong your out.");
                System.out.println("Also you will be competing against a super computer, after you play then he will generate answers, if you have the most then you win");
                System.out.println("Ok first question");
        }

        public static void human_Answer ()          // Human Answer Single Player Method
        {

             Scanner input2 = null;
            Object answer = input2.nextInt();
        }

        static void player_One_Answer()     // Player One Multiplayer Method
        {
             Scanner input2 = null;
            int player_One_Answer = input2.nextInt();
        }

        public static void player_Two_Answer()      // Player two multiplayer Method
        {
             Scanner input2 = null;
            int player_Two_Answer = input2.nextInt();
        }

        public static void computer_Answer ()       // Computer answer
        {
             double computer_Answer = (1-1 + 1) * Math.random() + 1;
             computer_Answer = (int)computer_Answer;
        }

        public static void question_One()           // Question 1 method
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("What is an application");
            System.out.println("1: A program that performs a task   2:A mouse   3: java.util.Scanner");


        }

        public static void question_Two()       // Question 2 to 10 methods below
        {

            System.out.println("What is the data type that hold the value 1");
            System.out.println("1: int  2:float 3: short 4: long ");

        }

        public static void question_Three()
        {
            System.out.println("What is a not a high level language");
            System.out.println("1: Java     2:C++   3: Colbolt      4: Machine Language ");
        }

    /*  public static void question_Five()
        {

        }

        public static void question_Six()
        {

        }

        public static void question_Seven()
        {

        }

        public static void question_Eight()
        {

        }

        public static void question_Nine()
        {

        }

        public static void question_Ten()
        {

        }

        public static void total_Winnings_Single_Player ()      // Calculating who wins method single player
        {
            if (computer_Winnings > winnings)
            {
                System.out.println("Computer Wins");
            }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You win");
                }
                */
        }



    // I get infinite loop om my while statements and I get an exepction error on my values with null
```

Comment: Try to [trim](http://sscce.org) the code and post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Please autoformat the code (Ctrl+Shift+F in Eclipse)

Comment: Your post needs formating, trimming and more information(where is the stacktrace?)

Comment: You are nulling out your Scanner before trying to use it in your answer methods which obviously results in an NPE. Also your first while loop will run forever if answer is < 1 and > 3. Apart from that your code has a ton of other problems..

Answer (score 1):

This is because `input2`  is `null` try this:

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```